# Unable to find cause of 403 Forbidden error: Nginx Daphne Django

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels, daphne

I have had confirmation in another question that I can indeed run a Django app using only `Nginx` and `Daphne` and have modified my `nginx` config code as per their suggestion.

The application is running with Daphne on 127.0.0.1:8001

However, I am running into a 403 Forbidden error. The nginx error logs say:

```
"2019/03/07 11:23:48 [error] 16642#16642: *11 directory index of "/path/to/app" is forbidden, client: xx.xxx.xx.xx, server: app.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.app.com", referrer: "http://www.app.com""
```

I'm still facing a 403 and would be grateful to anyone who may be able to locate where the problem is coming from.

My nginx config

```
upstream socket {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name your.server.com;
    access_log /etc/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/someroot;

    location / {
            #autoindex on;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            # try_files $uri =404;

            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            #proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            #proxy_pass http://socket;
            #proxy_redirect off;
            #proxy_http_version 1.1;
            #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

            #proxy_redirect off;
            #proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            #proxy_cache one;
            #proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/some/fullchain.pem;
    # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/some/privkey.pem; 
    # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: `autoindex` by default is off, that's why attempt to browse a "directory" raises 403. This error is returned by nginx because `proxy_pass` to django app is disabled.

Comment: How do I enable `proxy_pass` to a django app?

Comment: Try to uncomment it.

Comment: Ha ha wow it's been a long day

Comment: I now get a 404 Not Found, when I uncomment that block, which I assume is because it can't serve it as a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change `try_files $uri=404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` and that fixed the issue of the main page however other pages still display 404 error.